# tryCatch does not seem to return my variable

Tags: r, error-handling

I'm trying to use tryCatch to generate a list of p-values there are several rows in the matrix that don't have enough observations for a t test. Here is the code I generated so far:

```
pValues <- c()
for(i in row.names(collapsed.gs.raw)){
  tryCatch({
    t <- t.test(as.numeric(collapsed.gs.raw[i,]) ~ group)
    pValues <- c(pValues, t$p.value)
  },
  error = function(err) {
    pValues <- c(pValues, "NA")
    message("Error")
    return(pValues)
  })}
```

It definitely throws an error [I put in the message("Error") line to confirm]. The problem is that the vector pValues doesn't have any "NA" in it, though it should.

Thanks in advance for your help!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The `pvalues` in your function is a local variable.  You might be able to fix this with `<<-`, but it would be preferred to have the function just return the one desired value and collect them outside the function with `sapply`.  Perhaps something like (untested):

```
pValues <- sapply(rownames(collapsed.gs.raw), function(i) {
  tryCatch({
    t.test(as.numeric(collapsed.gs.raw[i,]) ~ group)$p.value
  },
  error = function(err) {
    message("Error")
    return(NA)
  })
})
```

Comment: Brutal! It worked perfectly and it makes perfect sense. Thanks @Aaron for your quick and great response!