# Using tryCatch to assign objects to loop elements that yield an error

Tags: r, list, loops, try-catch, read.csv

I am trying to read thousands of .csv files into a list. The files are named with running numbers, f.ex. file1.csv, file2.csv. Occasionally a file doesn't exist. When it doesn't exist, I want to assign to that element of the list a placeholder vector `rep(NA,9)`. I've tried the following loop:

```
file.numbers = 1:2000
data = list()

for (i in 1:2000) {
  tryCatch(
    data[[i]] = read.csv((paste("file", file.numbers[i], sep = ""))),
    error=function(e){data[[i]] = rep(NA,9)}
  )
}
```

Lets say file1052.csv doesn't exist. I would like to have `data[[1052]] = rep(NA,9)`, but instead the above loop gives me `data[[1052]] = NULL`. What to do?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [tryCatch does not seem to return my variable](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21956031/trycatch-does-not-seem-to-return-my-variable)

Answer (score 0):

You can use `file.exists`

```
file.numbers = 1:2000
data = list()
for (i in 1:2000) {
  filename <- paste("file", file.numbers[i],".csv", sep = "")
  if(file.exists(filename)){
    data[[i]] = read.csv(filename)
  } else {
    data[[i]] = rep(NA,9)
  }
}
```

Comment: This works! Can you give me the reason why my code does not work?

Comment: It's because you get out of your tryCatch block as soon as an error occurs. So your line `error=function(e){rep(NA,9)}` isn't read when the file doesn't exist

Answer (score 0):

Try:

```
for (i in 1:2000) {
  csv.i <-
  tryCatch(read.csv(paste("file", file.numbers[i], sep = "")),
error=function(e){rep(NA,9)}
  )
data[[i]] <- csv.i
}
```