# Perform two-sample t-test and output the t, p values for two groups of matrices in R

Tags: r

I am trying to perform a two-sample t-test like this

[image]

The `wt1`, `wt2`, `wt3`, `mut1`, `mut2`, `mut3` are 3x3 matrices. After running the t-test, I would like to get `t.stat` and `p.value` matrices, in which

```
t.stat[i,j] <- the t value from t.test(c(wt1[i,j],wt2[i,j],wt3[i,j]),c(mut1[i,j],mut2[i,j],mut3[i,j]))
p.value[i,j] <- the p-value from t.test(c(wt1[i,j],wt2[i,j],wt3[i,j]),c(mut1[i,j],mut2[i,j],mut3[i,j]))
```

with `i` and `j` indicating the row and column indices.

Is there an efficient way to achieve this without a loop?

---

Thank you very much for the help, it works!

Now I found that my data in the diagonal directions are all 1, which would result in `Error in t.test.default(c(wt1[x], wt2[x], wt3[x]), c(mut1[x], mut2[x],  : 
  data are essentially constant`.

In order to pass those errors, I would like to output `N/A` in the `t.stat` and `p.value`. If the matrices have to contain the same type of values, `0` and `1` can be used for `t.stat` and `p.value`, respectively. It seems that `tryCatch` can do the job, but I am not sure how to handle it with `sapply`?

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can do something like this:

```
test<- sapply(1:9, function(x) t.test(c(wt1[x], wt2[x], wt3[x]), 
                                      c(mut1[x], mut2[x], mut3[x])))
t.stat<- matrix(test["statistic", ], nrow = 3)
p.value<- matrix(test["p.value", ], nrow = 3)
```

For the second part of your question, I think using `tryCatch` inside `sapply` will help. Unfortunately, I couldn't think of a way of pre-allocating `test` and then creating the 2 matrices while using `tryCatch`. In order to do that, I am adapting [Aaron's answer.](https://stackoverflow.com/a/21956120/7945273)

```
t.stat<- matrix(sapply(1:9, function(x) 
                                  tryCatch({t.test(c(wt1[x], wt2[x], wt3[x]), 
                                                 c(mut1[x], mut2[x], mut3[x]))$statistic},
                             error = function(err) {return(NA)})), nrow = 3)

p.value<- matrix(sapply(1:9, function(x) 
                                  tryCatch({t.test(c(wt1[x], wt2[x], wt3[x]), 
                                                 c(mut1[x], mut2[x], mut3[x]))$p.value},
                             error = function(err) {return(NA)})), nrow = 3)
```

Comment: Pretty much. You could also save the results of the `sapply` + `t.test` once and then extract the parts. `lapply(results, \`[\`, c("statistic","p.value"))` or similar I think.

Comment: @thelatemail Excellent suggestion! I edited the answer accordingly!

Comment: Thank you very much Yannis for your help! I updated the question, can you help me again? @thelatemail